# Multiparty library, not receiving file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multipart

I am trying to implement a file uploader in my rest API. My technologies are node and mongo.

My controller looks like:

```
API.uploadFile = function(req, res) {

    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
       res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
       res.write('received upload:\n\n');
       res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
  }
```

When I perform the following curl:

```
curl -v -include -F path='/Users/marc/Desktop/picture-1-1024x768.jpg' http://127.0.0.1:8000/images
```

The answer is:

{ fields: { path: [ '/Users/marc/Desktop/picture-1-1024x768.jpg' ] },
  files: {} }

Why the files is empty??

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the curl format. The correct one is:

```
curl -v -include -F path="@/Users/marc/Desktop/picture-1-1024x768.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:8000/images
```

Yes the @ character made it work. Apparently is the curl syntax http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#File_Upload_POST